# Monitor questions without answering

Tags: support, questions, bookmarks

Is it possible to monitor questions without giving an answer to them and get notified of new answers or list them on my profile page or a dedicated sub-page. I sometimes find interesting question, which I myself cannot answer but want to know what others say about it. I know, I can always pollute my browser favourites, but I think such a feature would be quite useful, if not already there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can "favourite" a question by clicking on the star underneath the vote up/down counters. The star will turn yellow and show a number underneath of how many people have favourited the question. The favourites will then appear on a profile tab.

Comment: but his request is , if those favourite questions been answered, then their should be some notification .

Comment: @Damodar When it shows on a dedicated page, I'm actually quite satisfied. But notification could be a future feature.

Comment: There *is* a notification when "favorite" questions are answered. The [Favorites](http://stackoverflow.com/users/743214/christian-rau?tab=favorites) tab in your user profile has a numerical indicator. In the wee olden days, the envelope used to light up, but that's long-gone now.

Comment: Oh yes, I just noticed that. Now I'm really satisfied, as the whole feature is there and I just couldn't seem to find it.